# How to animate a rectangle on a polar plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, polar-coordinates

I have been trying to animate a polar plot in which I have a one degree wide wedge sweep all the way around the plot in a circle. I tried using the code below, but for some reason, it gives me the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'`. I was trying to initialize the wedge as a rectangle patch that starts off on the right side of the plot and increases in x (angle), so I thought I should update the x-coordinate in the animate function, but for some reason, whenever I return patch (the rectangle) from animation, it gives me an error. Any tips? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
_, rlim = ax.get_ylim()
patch = Rectangle((0,0), np.radians(1), rlim)

def init():
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    return patch,

def animate(i):
    patch.set_xy((np.radians(i), 0))
    return patch,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=360, interval=30, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 114, in _on_timer
    TimerBase._on_timer(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1187, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1449, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1169, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1189, in _draw_next_frame
    self._post_draw(framedata, blit)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1212, in _post_draw
    self._blit_draw(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1229, in _blit_draw
    bg_cache[a.axes] = a.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(a.axes.bbox)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

Comment: Thanks! Still gives the same error tho...

Comment: For me it seems to work as intended adding `init_func=init` to `FuncAnimation`. Maybe it helps if you restart Python?

Comment: That worked. Thank you!